# Strange problem comparing floats in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c, casting, floating-point

At some point in an algorithm I need to compare the float value of a property of a class to a float. So I do this:

```
if (self.scroller.currentValue <= 0.1) {
}
```

where currentValue is a float property.

However, when I have equality and `self.scroller.currentValue = 0.1` the if statement is not fulfilled and the code not executed! I found out that I can fix this by casting 0.1 to float. Like this:

```
if (self.scroller.currentValue <= (float)0.1) {
}
```

This works fine.

Can anyone explain to my why this is happening? Is 0.1 defined as a double by default or something?

Thanks.

Comment: See also, "What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic:"

http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: For those of you (especially @alastair) who have worked to improve my answer, I'm not convinced it could be improved. I agree it was incorrect and probably dangerous. I've deleted it. Please see James Snook's answer for a much deeper exploration of this non-trivial problem.

Comment: @RobNapier I have to say that I thought it worthwhile keeping the answer, with the corrections added, but I understand your perspective on it. Apologies if my edit seemed a little aggressive — I just wanted to make it clear what the problem was.

Comment: @alastair Not at all; it helped get rid of something I think was misleading people (including myself). I'd rather improve James Snook's answer with anything you'd like to add. Wrongness on SO, even *marked* wrong, can sometimes be confusing to readers. If your rep doesn't let you see deleted posts, and you want to copy something you previously wrote into your own answer or James's, I've posted the old text here (and also for anyone curious what we're talking about :D): https://gist.github.com/rnapier/78502480e53f526d24f30a14032dea8d)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I believe, having not found the standard that says so, that when comparing a `float` to a `double` the `float` is cast to a `double` before comparing. Floating point numbers without a modifier are considered to be `double` in C.

However, in C there is no exact representation of 0.1 in floats and doubles. Now, using a float gives you a small error. Using a double gives you an even smaller error. The problem now is, that by casting the `float` to a `double` you carry over the bigger of error of the `float`. Of course they aren't gone compare equal now.

Instead of using `(float)0.1` you could use `0.1f` which is a bit nicer to read.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, as you have suggested in your question, that you are comparing a float with a double.

There is a more general problem with comparing floats, this happens because when you do a calculation on a floating point number the result from the calculation may not be exactly what you expect. It is fairly common that the last bit of the resulting float will be wrong (although the inaccuracy can be larger than just the last bit). If you use `==` to compare two floats then all the bits have to be the same for the floats to be equal. If your calculation gives a slightly inaccurate result then they won't compare equal when you expect them to. Instead of comparing the values like this, you can compare them to see if they are nearly equal. To do this you can take the positive difference between the floats and see if it is smaller than a given value (called an epsilon).

To choose a good epsilon you need to understand a bit about floating point numbers. Floating point numbers work similarly to representing a number to a given number of significant figures. If we work to 5 significant figures and your calculation results in the last digit of the result being wrong then 1.2345 will have an error of +-0.0001 whereas 1234500 will have an error of +-100. If you always base your margin of error on the value 1.2345 then your compare routine will be identical to `==` for all values great than 10 (when using decimal). This is worse in binary, it's all values greater than 2. This means that the epsilon we choose has to be relative to the size of the floats that we are comparing.

FLT_EPSILON is the gap between 1 and the next closest float. This means that it may be a good epsilon to choose if your number is between 1 and 2, but if your value is greater than 2 using this epsilon is pointless because the gap between 2 and the next nearest float is larger than epsilon. So we have to choose an epsilon relative to the size of our floats (as the error in the calculation is relative to the size of our floats).

A good(ish) floating point compare routine looks something like this:

```
bool compareNearlyEqual (float a, float b, unsigned epsilonMultiplier)       
{
  float epsilon;
  /* May as well do the easy check first. */
  if (a == b)
    return true;

  if (a > b) {
    epsilon = scalbnf(1.0f, ilogb(a)) * FLT_EPSILON * epsilonMultiplier;
  } else {
    epsilon = scalbnf(1.0, ilogb(b)) * FLT_EPSILON * epsilonMultiplier;
  }

  return fabs (a - b) <= epsilon;
}
```

This comparison routine compares floats relative to the size of the largest float passed in. `scalbnf(1.0f, ilogb(a)) * FLT_EPSILON` finds the gap between `a` and the next nearest float. This is then multiplied by the `epsilonMultiplier`, so the size of the difference can be adjusted, depending on how inaccurate the result of the calculation is likely to be.

You can make a simple `compareLessThan` routine like this:

```
bool compareLessThan (float a, float b, unsigned epsilonMultiplier)
{
  if (compareNearlyEqual (a, b, epsilonMultiplier)
    return false;

  return a < b;
}
```

You could also write a very similar `compareGreaterThan` function.

It's worth noting that comparing floats like this may not always be what you want. For instance this will never find that a float is close to 0 unless it is 0. To fix this you'd need to decide what value you thought was close to zero, and write an additional test for this.

Sometimes the inaccuracies you get won't depend on the size of the result of a calculation, but will depend on the values that you put into a calculation. For instance `sin(1.0f + (float)(200 * M_PI))` will give a much less accurate result than `sin(1.0f)` (the results should be identical). In this case your compare routine would have to look at the number you put into the calculation to know the margin of error of the answer.

Comment: What is `epsilonMultiplier`?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw `epsilonMultiplier` allows you to adjust the size of the epsilon. For instance setting it to `1` allows the closest two floats to the desired result to count as equal. Increasing it increases the number of values that will compare equal. You can reason about the size `epsilonMultiplier` should be based on how a value is calculated, or by experimentation.

Answer (score 4):

Doubles and floats have different values for the mantissa store in binary (float is 23 bits, double 54). These will almost never be equal.

[The IEEE Float Point article on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) may help you understand this distinction.

Answer (score 4):

In C, a floating-point literal like 0.1 is a double, not a float.  Since the types of the data items being compared are different, the comparison is done in the more precise type (double).  In all implementations I know about, float has a shorter representation than double (usually expressed as something like 6 vs. 14 decimal places).  Moreover, the arithmetic is in binary, and 1/10 does not have an exact representation in binary.

Therefore, you're taking a float 0.1, which loses accuracy, extending it to double, and expecting it to compare equal to a double 0.1, which loses less accuracy.

Suppose we were doing this in decimal, with float being three digits and double being six, and we were comparing to 1/3.

We have the stored float value being 0.333.  We're comparing it to a double with value 0.333333.  We convert the float 0.333 to double 0.333000, and find it different.

Comment: Following this thought in decimal (which has different hard numbers than binary, but the concept is the same) you will find that (1/3)*3 != 1, no matter how many (finite) digits you choose. This is why doing all your math in float or double doesn't really fix the problem.

Comment: Right.  Of course, you can get arbitrarily close to 1 by using enough digits, so testing for getting really close works a lot better than testing for equality.  The real issue here is that floating-point equality tests do not in general work.

Comment: Agreed. Thus the available warning (which I recommend turning on) to prevent you from accidentally using floating point equality.

Answer (score 4):

0.1 is actually a very dificult value to store binary. In base 2, 1/10 is the infinitely repeating fraction

```
0.0001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011...
```

As several has pointed out, the comparison has to made with a constant of the exact same precision.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in any language, you can't really count on equality of float-like types. In your case since it looks like you have more control, it does appear that 0.1 is not float by default.  You could probably find that out with sizeof(0.1) (vs. sizeof(self.scroller.currentValue).

Comment: sizeof reveals that 0.1 is a double. It is still very strange that you don't get equality when both have the value 0.10000 isn't it?

Comment: @Dimitris, it's not that strange.  See @MarkPowell's answer.

Comment: @Dimitris: No, that's not very odd. 0.1 is not precisely representable in binary. As Lou said, don't count on equality in floating point numbers. Ever. Check if the numbers are within some tiny margin of each other (e.g., `(a - m < b) && (a + m > b)`).

Answer (score -1):

Convert it to a string, then compare:

```
NSString* numberA = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", a];
NSString* numberB = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.6f", b];

return [numberA isEqualToString: numberB];
```